# WebLogic logs containing BEA-180029 - <Caught this Ferror exception: 5 (FBADFLD). Additional exception info found: Unknown fldid32: 168877871>

Tags: weblogic

may i know if someone has encountered this before? Found this in WebLogic 
managed server logs.

```
####<Jul 15, 2011 9:59:34 AM EST> <Error> <WTC> <mi009.aiu.com> <ilpmServer3> <ExecuteThread: '58' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default'> <ICO_WS1> <> <BEA-180029> <Caught this Ferror exception: 5 (FBADFLD). Additional exception info found: Unknown fldid32: 168877871>
```

The exception explanation at [WebLogic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/messages/WTC.html) does not provide much information about the error.

Comment: no, this log was appended to another logger which does not log the tracestack.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that WLS is calling a TUXEDO server via WTC Tuxedo server is calling a WLS services exported via WTC.

In any of both cases the FIELDID 168877871 is not mapped to the same variable by Tuxedo server OR WLS code.

Please verify with the developers of the app if the FIELDID 168877871 correspond to the same variable for WLS and Tuxedo Server.

In Tuxedo server  please check the files of)

`env | egrep "FIELDTBLS|FLDTBLDIR"`

In Java verify the source.